# Meteor each loop data not displaying

Tags: meteor

In each loop data is not displaying.value="{{param_type}}" not displaying.Please help me.

```
{{ #each api_method_param_data }}
    <select id="param_type"> 
    {{#each dropdown}}
    {{#if isSelected this param_type}}  
    <option value="{{param_type}}" selected="selected"> {{this}} </option>
    {{else}}
    <option value="{{param_type}}" > {{this}} </option>
    {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
    </select>
 {{/each}}
```

This is the helper function

```
 Template.apimethodchange.isSelected = function(fooToCheck, recordFoo)
  {
    var checkrec = "";  
    for(var i=0;i<recordFoo.length;i++)
    {
        checkrec = checkrec + recordFoo[i];
    }
    console.log(checkrec + fooToCheck);
    return (fooToCheck == checkrec);
  };

Template.apimethodchange.dropdown = ["string","array","int","boolean","double","struct"];
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the data context or helper function looks like?

Comment: I am added the helper function Please check once.@richsilv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `../` to access parent context

```
<option value="{{../param_type}}" selected="selected"> {{this}} </option>
```